# Linear Regression In R and test of constant variance

Tags: r, anova, predictive-models

I am trying to construct a regression model in R.I am getting an error while predicting the model. I am not sure if the newdata(which is my validation set) should be a data frame?

```
data<-read.csv("training.csv")
data<- na.omit(data)
model<-lm(Y ~ X1+X2+...+X10, data=data)
newdata<-read.csv("validation.csv")
predict(model,newdata)
```

I am new to statistic and was trying to perform bartlett test and leneve test to test for constant variance. I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.

```
bartlett.test(list(X1,X2,X3..X10),data= data)
levene.test(X1,X2..., X10, location="mean")
```

It would be great if anyone could help.

Answer (score 2):

1) Not only should your new data be a data frame, all the x-variables (the columns of the data frame) should have exactly the same names as the original data.

2) you don't specify a sequence of X's by putting "`..`" between them in R

3) The Bartlett and Levene (NOT Leneve) tests are for comparing variances of conditional y's, not x's. You need grouping variables for those tests, and to my knowledge `levene.test` is not in vanilla R.

`levene.test` presumably in some package; you should state which one you're using.  There's discussion of one [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15722/how-to-use-levene-test-function-in-r), which suggests it may be in some package loaded by  Rcmdr (or one you can use with it). The package `car` has `leveneTest`.

Edit: the packages `lawstat` and `s20x` have `levene.test` functions, and it's also a deprecated function in `car`

Comment: I am little confused about using bartlett test. We use it in comparing the variances of Y. In my case I only have one target variable and 16 input variable. So how does it work. It would be great if you could help.

Comment: I've responded to that already in my answer ("*you need grouping variables for those tests*"). The [Bartlett test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartlett's_test) is explicitly for comparing variances of groups. If your "16 variables" don't divide the data into a (moderate) number of mutually exclusive groups each of which has a large enough sample size to estimate a variance (and you don't have some other obvious way of dividing your residuals up into groups), you probably don't want to use the Bartlett test.